# doctrine 2 orm and sql injection

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, sql-injection, database-security

In doctrine 2, how can I protect against sql injections when using ORM? I found the following page on the doctrine site:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/security.html

However that is about dbal and not about ORM.

Is it safe to use things like below assuming that $id is a posted value?

```
$entityManager->getRepository('Product')->find($id);
```

Or is it better to create the query instead using named parameters like this:

```
// DQL Prepared Statements
$dql = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.id = ?1";
$query = $em->createQuery($dql);
$query->setParameter(1, $_GET['pid']);
$data = $query->getResult();
```

Please note that I don't seek just a yes or no answer, but whether there is some authoritative documentation that ensures that this is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer on this page: [http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm).

Comment: That page no longer exists. I guess the page you refered to is this: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/security.html#security